# Информационный бот на С++

Tags: c++, telegram-bot, telegram

Имеется некая установка, информация подается на комп. Который сейчас время от времени отправляет e-mail'ы о происходящем по нужным адресам.

Захотелось сделать Telegram-канал и бота, который просто будет, когда надо, слать туда информацию.

Увы, все ссылки, которые перерыл,

1. это в основном описание чат-ботов
2. это в основном Python с какими-то страшными библиотеками
3. Пару статей о таком простом боте сводятся к использованию IFTTT, что мне совсем не нужно!

Соответственно, подскажите, где прочесть, или просто намекните, как должен работать такой бот - на С++, curl я как-нибудь прикручу. Все, что он должен делать - отправлять текст. Пока :)
Форматированный текст и изображения - приятный бонус, но пока хватит и просто текста.

Что-то у меня ощущение, что он просто должен отправлять запрос на сервер Telegram, но какой запрос, куда, какого формата - так и не смог найти.

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на англоязычном SO, там полно примеров - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465597/c-telegram-bot-post-request-for-updates-no-result), [2](https://medium.com/javarevisited/sending-a-message-to-a-telegram-channel-the-easy-way-eb0a0b32968). Всё что требуется - это API ключ бота, авторизованный для канала, CHAT_ID ну и собственно payload.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Мне кажется, что 1 - это получение информации, а не отправка? 2- ну, я попробую... но почему-то везде пишут, что метод отправки POST, а тут GET - оно, конечно, только проще :), но сработает ли?

Comment: Да, пардон, не заметил, вторая ссылка вам будет полезнее первой.

Comment: Еще несколько полезных ссылок: [доступные методы](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods), [отправить сообщение](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), [отправка фото](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) - *пролистайте дальше для аудио/видео и т.д.*, [отправка файлов по ID или URL](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files), [форматирование текста](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) - *не забудьте указать верный `parse_mode` при отправке сообщения!*

Comment: Запросы отправляются в формате `https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/method` Слово *bot* перед токеном **обязательно**. Это просто слово, **не** имя бота. Для получения событий в беседе можно использовать `WebHook` (телеграмм сам примылает новые события на ваш сервер - требуется HTTPS) или  `getUpdates` (вы переодически спрашиваете сервер телеграмма о произошедших событиях). О поддерживаемых методах запросов (GET/POST) и о том, как нужно формировать данные можно почитать [здесь](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests)

Comment: Пользовался вот [этим](https://github.com/StefanoBelli/xxtelebot) - C++ обертка вокруг API телеги. Работает нормально.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, заработало!